# CSS forms - input width not working

Tags: css

The following css:

```
#contactform {
    width: 400px;
    height: 215px;
}

.webform {
}

.webform input .name {
    width: 50px;
}

.webform input .email {
    width: 70px;
}

.webform input .comments {
    width: 200px;
}
```

when used in html as

```
    <div id="contactform">
        <div class="webform">
            <input class="name" name="Name" type="text" id="senderName" placeholder="Enter your name here">
            <input class="email" name="Email" type="text" id="senderEmail" placeholder="Enter a valid email adress here">
            <br>
            <input class="comments" name="Comments" type="text" id="senderComments" placeholder="Comments...">
        </div>
    </div>
```

produces all three input field of the same width (50px = that is, the width of the `webform input`). I'm not sure what I'm doing wrong. Help?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

your classes are on your `input`s, not on child elements of the `input`s. so change `input .name`, etc., to `input.name` or just `.name`, repeat for all three. :)

Comment: Thank you for the succinct explanation!

Answer (score 5):

remove the whitespace between your input and class name

```
.webform input.name {
    width: 50px;
}

.webform input.email {
    width: 70px;
}

.webform input.comments {
    width: 200px;
}
```

Try this [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/tFQJe/)

Comment: Thank you... when you know something, it doesn't take long!

Comment: @UmeshA Thanks for the fiddle link.